# Not able to use Beautifulsoup in PyCharm

Tags: beautifulsoup, pycharm

Seems like PyCharm cannot read Beautifulsoup in my code. Can someone help me with this issue.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
print(response.headers)
scr =response.content
soup = Beautifulsoup(src,'lxml')
links=soup.find_all("a")
print(links)
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Simon/PycharmProjects/Scraping/web_scraping", line 10, in <module>
    soup = Beautifulsoup4(src,'lxml')
NameError: name 'Beautifulsoup4' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be calling `Beautifulsoup()`, and the compiler is saying you are calling `Beautifulsoup4()` rather than `BeautifulSoup()`.

Try correcting this, then saving and recompiling your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the class `BeautifulSoup` and generating an object with the class `Beautifulsoup` (no capital s). Need to generate the `soup` object with `BeautifulSoup`, like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')
```

Also I recommend you the import the module like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

Do not need to write "BeautifulSoup" everytime you generate a `soup` object.

Comment: Great it works with: soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml') . Many thanks